# Center div based on right-edge of another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a website with a menubar on the left and the main content in the middle. I would like the empty space on either side of the content to be equal, even when resizing the browser.

Here's a rough demo: https://codepen.io/t-silver/pen/RMPmPW

However, currently the content dissapears underneath the menubar when resizing. I understand this has to do with the position:fixed, but experimenting with other positions, float, etc. just result in the menubar's appearance breaking (no more full height, floating off the sides of the browser, etc.). I'd like the content to treat the right side of the menubar as it is currently treating the left-side of the browser window.

How do I achieve this without breaking the menubar?

Html and CSS snippet:

```css
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5882fa;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5882fa;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: "Mina", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000917;
}

#sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#sidebar ul {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
}

#title {
  font-size: 180%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
}

.column {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 7px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 7px;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.collapse {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.chaps {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000917;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.collapse:hover .chaps {
  visibility: visible;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="title">
      <h1>Nature you crazy</h1>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="birds.html">Birds</a></li>
      <li><a href="crocodiles.html">Crocodiles</a></li>
      <li><a href="buffalos.html">Buffalos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="collapse">
      <img class="fade" src="http://www.nature-scene.net/ns/img/images/news/ph_001.jpg" />
      <h1 class="chaps">Pushing daisies</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Hello
      </p>
    </div>

    ...

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this, should be okay as long as the menu is a fixed width:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(125px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(125px);
  -o-transform: translateX(125px);
  transform: translateX(125px);
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted, thank you. My next step is to make the content more responsive, would this still be a viable solution when the screen becomes very narrow?

Comment: On mobile? No, because you still have px based widths. You would need to make it fluid.

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding` to your body tag equal to the sidenavs `width` in your case `padding-left:250px;`

```css
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5882fa;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5882fa;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: "Mina", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  padding-left:250px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000917;
}

#sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#sidebar ul {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
}

#title {
  font-size: 180%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
}

.column {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 7px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 7px;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.collapse {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.chaps {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000917;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.collapse:hover .chaps {
  visibility: visible;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
 <body>
      <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="title">
          <h1>Nature you crazy</h1>
        </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="birds.html">Birds</a></li>
      <li><a href="crocodiles.html">Crocodiles</a></li>
      <li><a href="buffalos.html">Buffalos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="collapse">
      <img class="fade" src="http://www.nature-scene.net/ns/img/images/news/ph_001.jpg" />
      <h1 class="chaps">Pushing daisies</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Hello
      </p>
    </div>
...

  </div>

</body>
```